# Building your own web controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

Well it's kind of a newbie question but I think lots of people have problems with this.

I'm developing Windows/web application for fun, and installing them at friends' places. Most of my developing concentrates on the CRM system, but I have a big problem with showing data from DB in better, more effective and lighter ways.

Using Microsoft built-in web controls is a nice and easy way, but it doesn't answer my needs, and worse, it's not that effective as other web controls in great software and websites(Google(lol)).

I want to build my own controls(GridView, etc...). So my question is how can I do this myself?

How does Microsoft build their web controls for both web and Windows Form developing?

Thanks!

Amit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the starting place for learning about creating your own web controls.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386565.aspx

And here's an older reference, but probably a better place to start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa710843(VS.71).aspx

And finally.... If you want to develop custom controls for Windows Forms applications...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Well, this can be answered several ways. Most of the nice controls are doing a lot of Javascript that is not obvious unless you look at the output. You might be interested in using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugins (or "controls"). Also, to be honest, you might be interested in persuing a new way of doing ASP.NET, which is called ASP.NET MVC. This is a very good way forward of building Web applications that utilize a lot of Web standard technologies without hiding and obscuring the details. Here's a link to that:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/

Comment: Very good answer.  I'm one of the MVC "haters", but I recognize that this is a weakness of my own.  I'm just too set in my "classic" asp.Net ways.  However, if you're looking for finer control, and cleaner separation of concerns, MVC looks like a good route to go.

Comment: Thanks both of you very much,
never thought to take look of the output of the page
MVC is a great way, and thank you. 
but those are still tools microsofts gives you, i want to build it my own way,therefore i know how my controller perfectly works and how effective it is. i guess i will go to learn some java script and remember some html tags, then i will take dataset or datatable and build a function which know to generate html\java script that build my own table, can i use StringBuilder for that? how can i take the StringBuilder and insert it into the viewed page? Thanks A lot. Amit